# Casting generic type to its non-nullable form

Tags: c#

I have the following method

```
public ValidationOutput PerformMatch<T>(IEnumerable<T> values, decimal maximum)
```

`values` can be`Int32?` `Int64?` or `decimal?`. *All* elements of `values` for a call of this method will be one of these types, but we don't know which they will all be in advance.

I need to check if each element of Values is null, if not, cast them to the non-nullable versions, so that I can then do comparisons against `maximum` which is always a `decimal`.

That is I would `ToList()` values and then do something like

```
if(Math.Abs((Int32)Values[i]-(Int32)Values[i+1])) < maximum)
{
}
```

My question is how can I do this casting with generic types? If it can't be done then is my only option to have 3 PerformMatch methods that have almost duplicated code?

Edit: The main issue I have is Math.Abs requires a non-nullable type. I am having difficulty casting a generic type to a non-nullable type

Comment: Why that method has to be generic? Why can't you have separate methods for each numeric type which you use.

Comment: Please explain what the "non-nullable form" of an anonymous type would be.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, because the method is much larger and there would be a lot of code duplication

Comment: @k29: Then extract the common code into a private helper method.

Comment: Your terminology is off.  T is not an anonymous type; it is a generic type parameter.  Read up on "generic type constraints" if you are not already familiar with the concept.

Comment: @k29 Then post the code. what are they types `T` can be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, add `Nullable` to the definition of the type:

```
public ValidationOutput PerformMatch<T>(IEnumerable<Nullable<T>> values, decimal maximum)
```

Then, you can access the nullability information without a problem. After that, simply use `Convert.ToDecimal` method to get the decimal value.

```
if(Values[i].HasValue)
{
    T val = Values[i].Value;
    decimal valDec = Convert.ToDecimal(val);
    // do whatever.
}
```

Comment: This worked, I as long as I add `where T: struct` to the end of the method (as in Phoog's answer), to convert values toList. The Convert.ToDecimal was helpful as far as casting is concerned so that I can use Math.Abs

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
public ValidationOutput PerformMatch<T>(IEnumerable<T?> values, decimal maximum)
where T : struct
```

Then you can use the HasValue property and the GetValueOrDefault method to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have three types, I would suggest not to use generics here:

```
public ValidationOutput PerformMatch(IEnumerable<Int32?> values, decimal maximum)
{
    return PerformMatch(values.Select(i => (decimal?)i), maximum);
}

public ValidationOutput PerformMatch(IEnumerable<Int64?> values, decimal maximum)
{
    return PerformMatch(values.Select(i => (decimal?)i), maximum);
}

public ValidationOutput PerformMatch(IEnumerable<decimal?> values, decimal maximum)
{
    // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you would like to list of all items in values which are not null.

```
var list = values.Where(x=>x.HasValue).ToList();
```

HasValue checks if item has value and is not null.